# Link to exported data

Tags: google-sheets, cognito-forms

I am using Google Sheets to import data from Cognito Forms. I need to download the .xlsx file every time I want to see results on my Excel sheet. I know that I can add a link to data in Google Sheets.

Is there any way I can have my data auto fetched from Cognito?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not offer a way to have information auto fetched or pushed out into other systems. You can set up a [Zapier](https://zapier.com) trigger, to preform an action when a form is submitted. This will not auto fetch new entries, but will have the same effect.